# i am trying to install django but getting error in path

Tags: django

The script django-admin.exe is installed in `'C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\Scripts'` which is not on PATH.

Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use `--no-warn-script-location`.

after running this command :-  `pip install django`
how can i fix it

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're trying to install Django globally. Instead of installing Django globally, it is best practice to provide a dedicated environment for each Django project you create.

To create a virtual environment for your project, open a new command prompt, navigate to the folder where you want to create your project and then enter: `py -m venv project-name`.

This will create a folder called ‘project-name’ if it does not already exist and set up the virtual environment. To activate the environment, run: `project-name\Scripts\activate.bat` The virtual environment will be activated and you’ll see “(project-name)” next to the command prompt to designate that. Each time you start a new command prompt, you’ll need to activate the environment again.

You can then install Django easily using pip within your virtual environment. In the command prompt, ensure your virtual environment is active, and execute the following command: `py -m pip install Django` This will download and install the latest Django release.

After the installation has completed, you can verify your Django installation by executing `django-admin --version` in the command prompt.

See [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/windows/) for more.